# How to jump to end of line in Visual Studio while using multi select

Tags: visual-studio

I know you can select multiple lines using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but how to jump to end of line while still
selecting the same lines. By the way, I am talking about the Visual Studio IDE, not VS Code.

Comment: Are you looking for SHIFT/END?

Comment: No I want to skip to end of each individual line of lines chosen

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only need 0-1 cursors per line, this combination of inputs will get you exactly what you asked, everything from the multi-cursor to the end of the line:

1. Multi-select (for example via Alt+Shift+ArrowDown)
2. then Shift+End
3. then Ctrl+Shift+Left
4. then Ctrl+Shift+Right

This works even if one or more of your cursors started at the end of line already!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).